# Displaying javascript style alert after form submit in Django

Tags: javascript, django

I am creating a simple application in Django. I have a form on a page and after the form is submitted, I want to redirect the user to a new page and display a JavaScript alert like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oph4G.png). How would I go about doing this? My code is down bellow.

---

**This is the function that stores the form data and redirects to a new page, the new page only has simple html on it.**

```
def donate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST['donationtitle']
        phonenumber = request.POST['phonenumber']
        category = request.POST['category']
        quantity = request.POST['quantity']
        location = request.POST['location']
        description = request.POST['description']
        # New part. Update donor's stats.
        UserDetail.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(donations=F('donations') + 1)
        UserDetail.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(points=F('points') + (quantity * 2))
        return render(request, 'dashboard.html', )
    return render(request,'donate.html')
```

I have done lot's of research but I can not find a logical solution to my problem. Past questions have asked me to use Django messages, which is something I don't want to use. Thank you to everyone who helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template, `dashboard.html` it appears to be, ensure that you load jquery, and then this will display an alert;

Add some context to your page to tell the template the form was submitted;

```
return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'form_submitted': True})
```

Then you can check if the form was submitted

```
{% if form_submitted %}
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    alert('Donor stats updated!');
  });
</script>
{% endif %}
```

Personally, I'd do this with djagno's messages though - nicer UX

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work. I want this alert to only show up if the user submits the form data, if I go to dashboard.html without submitting form data, the alert still shows up

Comment: @Jahan in that case, you need to tell the template the form was submitted. I've updated my answer.